# How to make existing Flutter App Project Responsive?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am working on a Flutter project currently and I suddenly realized that it was not responsive when I tried it on various android phones with different sizes and screen dimensions. There are some cases when the phone is big the text and images are not in their proper place and some overflows. I am already halfway with my project but I don't know how will it be responsive. Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Share some code snippets.

Comment: Which part of the code will I show? Currently I have 18 files already, its too much to show and I don't which part should I include and share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make responsive with [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) like:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    if (constraints.maxWidth  >= 600){
        return Widget(...); // if bigger than
    }
    return Widget(); // else use default
  }
)
```

You can use the `BoxConstraints` methods and check to show diffrent layout and widget

You can use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) too, just search about it but when we are talking about whole page structure in diffrent devices, its better to use `LayoutBuilder`

there are tons of videos for your purpose:

- [video from youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrPJBAOzKTQ)

Comment: Will that work even if I have an existing project already? My concern is that maybe I have to do so much work in fixing everything which could feel like I started again from scratch.

Comment: Yes, you have a code for one device right now, just make logic if device size is bigger show another layout and widgets

Comment: Do I have to edit all my files and put it in LayoutBuilder or just my main.dart file?

Comment: You need to make each screen responsive with layoutbuilder, watch videos, it show step by step,  you need to make code for each constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXwK1Lrfihw) and [document](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive) in the link. It gives good information about making responsive applications.

Comment: Will that work even if I have an existing project already? My concern is that maybe I have to do so much work in fixing everything which could feel like I started again from scratch.

Comment: It will work, but you will have to change a lot of things. You'll have to do it eventually, so I think it's best to do it now :)